# How does this code for adding 2 complex numbers work?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I came across the following code for adding/subtracting two complex numbers. I am a beginner at python, so I couldn't understand the code completely. Can you guys please help me understand the following code:

1. The significance of `__str__` method  in the code below.
2. The significance of "other" variable in `__add__` and `__sub__` methods i.e how are the values other.a and other.b returned from the input.

   ```
     class ComplexNumber(object):
         def __init__(self, a, b):
             '''a is real part and b is the imaginary part.'''
             self.a = a
             self.b = b

         def __str__(self):
             '''Represent complex number in a restrict way.'''
             if self.b == 0:
                 return "%.2f" % self.a
             elif self.a == 0:
                 #return "- %.2fi" % abs(self.b)
                 return "%.2fi" % self.b
             elif self.b < 0:
                 return "%.2f - %.2fi" % (self.a, abs(self.b))
             else:
                 return "%.2f + %.2fi" % (self.a, self.b)

         def __add__(self, other):
             return ComplexNumber(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)

         def __sub__(self, other):
             return ComplexNumber(self.a - other.a, self.b - other.b)

      a, b = [float(item) for item in raw_input().split()]
      c1 = ComplexNumber(a, b)
      a, b = [float(item) for item in raw_input().split()]
      c2 = ComplexNumber(a, b)

      print c1 + c2
      print c1 - c2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

#adding two complex numbers

```
 x=complex(input())
 y=complex(input())
 z=x+y
 print("The sum of complex numbers:",z)

 #output will be 
 3+2j
 4+5j
 The sum of complex numbers:7+7j'
```

Answer (score 0):

`__str__()` is the method that defines how you convert an object to a string.

The `other` variable is the object that you are adding to this object. The "other" object.

Comment: But, when you are printing c1 + c2, how is the add method being called here. I mean, how exactly is the addition happening?

Comment: `c1 + c2` is in this case done with a `c1.__add__(c2)`. Then the resulting ComplexNumber will be converted to a string with `__str__()` and printed.

Comment: When I tried running the code after I deleted the __str__ method, why isn't c1+c2 printing the same output?. Because to my uderstanding __str__ method is just changing the numbers to specific format and nothing else.

Comment: No, it's to convert it to a string, and print uses it to print things.